# Download file with Angular5

Tags: angular, download, angular5

I have an Angular 5 project that allows for a file upload, and I'd like to give the user an example/template file they can download first.

File structure

```
file-importer/
  | file-importer.component.html
  | file-importer.component.ts
  | example-file-template.csv
```

In that HTML file I want to do something like this

```
<a href='example-file-template.csv' download>
  Download a sample template here
</a>
```

But that link will be incorrect, so how am I supposed to link to static files like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your static files in the `/assets` folder. It's a special folder in Angular, that's where you're supposed to put all your static files, images etc. Then link them like this :

```
<a href='assets/example-file-template.csv' download>
  Download a sample template here
</a>
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!  I never really used that folder before.

Comment: how to prevent event bubbling here?

Comment: Is this folder hardcoded into Angular or can we chose from where to serve static assets?

Comment: Didn't work for me! Downloaded file is replace with the content of index.html